# Inner join with sum and less than

Tags: sql-server

I have created two tables fees and students. Now what I want to do is: inner join of them along with the sum of the amount paid by the students where sum of amount should > 500

I was able to do the inner join also the sum of the amounts but I couldn't show the amount > 500 along with sum and inner join

```
select s.firstname+''+s.Lastname [Name],sum(f.AMOUNT)[TotaAmount],f.REMARKS from std s
     inner join Fees f on 
     s.id=f.STUDENTID 
     group by firstname,Lastname
     where amount>500
```

what is expect is to get inner join together with the sum which > 500

Comment: What about `remarks`? You can't just select it. Group by it or aggregate it.

Comment: `WHERE` goes *before* the `GROUP BY` not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.firstname + '' + s.Lastname [Name], 
       sum(f.AMOUNT) [TotaAmount]
from std s
inner join Fees f on s.id = f.STUDENTID 
group by s.id, s.firstname, s.Lastname
having sum(f.AMOUNT) > 500
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `s.id` to the `GROUP BY`. A name is by far unique (I've met several people who have the same first and last name as me, and one of them even the same DoB).